# Convert `setInterval` to AngularJS with angularJS Services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to convert this to AngularJS, but I don't know where to start

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 1, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      $('#clock-days').text(days);
      $('#clock-hours').text(hours);
      $('#clock-minutes').text(minutes);
      $('#clock-seconds').text(seconds);     
    }, 1000);
```

First problem is that Math function is not available and how to write interval?

Comment: where Math not available? angularjs or angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace the `setInterval` with `$interval` in the controller, then change the var variables to scope variables, please study the below fiddle to identify the differences.

DEMO: [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/0o1ezx1j/1/)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
    var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 1, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = $interval(function() {

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      $scope.days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      $scope.hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      $scope.minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      $scope.seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);   
    }, 1000);
}]);
```